# Custom data annotation validation attribute with client side validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have made a custom data annotation attribute which verifies whether an email already exists in my database like this:

```
   public class ValidateEmail : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            using (var ctx = new myCtx())
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    var valueAsString = value.ToString().ToLower();
                    IEnumerable<string> email = ctx.Users.Where(x => x.Email != null).Select(x => x.Email);
                    if (email.Contains(valueAsString))
                    {
                        var errorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName);
                        return new ValidationResult(errorMessage);
                    }
                }
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
        }
    }
```

And in my view model I set it like this:

```
   [ValidateEmail(ErrorMessage = "Email exists")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
```

This works perfectly when the page reloads...But I would like now to change this so that I enable client side validation and message displaying without reloading the page itself...

How can I modify this validation attribute to make it compliable with jquery's unobstrusive validation in .NET MVC?

Based on @Sayan's link, I've implemented something like this:

```
   public class ValidateEmail : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
    {
        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {
            var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule();
            rule.ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName());
            rule.ValidationType = "emailvalidate";

            yield return rule;

        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            using (var ctx = new myContext())
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    var valueAsString = value.ToString().ToLower();
                    IEnumerable<string> email = ctx.Users.Where(x => x.Email != null).Select(x => x.Email);
                    if (email.Contains(valueAsString))
                    {
                        var errorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName);
                        return new ValidationResult(errorMessage);
                    }
                }
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
        }
    }
```

and client side:

```
$.validator.addMethod("emailvalidate", function (value, element) {
{
    console.log("value: " + value + " " + element);
}});
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("emailvalidate", function (options) {

      //adding rules for validator
    options.rules["emailvalidate"] = true;
    if (options.message) {
        options.messages["emailvalidate"] = options.message;
    }

});
```

But whatever I insert now in the email field as email like:

```
myemail@ymail.xyz
```

I get the error that email exists ?

Comment: Anyone guys ? =)

Comment: Use a `[Remote]` attribute if you want to call a server method. Do not put database calls in a `ValidationAttribute`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement [`IClientValidatable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iclientvalidatable(v=vs.118).aspx) in your `ValidateEmail` validation attribute to supply the `data-val-xxx` attributes to the client side.

Then you can write the jQuery unobtrusive validator and adapter to validate the field value on client side using the `data-val-xxx` rendered in HTML.

*Make sure to return `true` (truthy value) or `false` (falsy value) from the jQuery validator based on whether the field value is valid or not respectively.*

Lastly, include this custom jQuery validator script to your view.

You can find more details [here](http://programersnotebook.blogspot.de/2013/03/customizing-validation-attributes-in-mvc.html). Though this blog post presents a slightly complicated scenario, but seeing how to use `IClientValidatable` and how to write jQuery unobtrusive validator is enough.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Hey Sayan thanks a lot for the reply.. I have implemented it "partially", but it always displays the error message that email exists... I will edit my initial question with solution I wrote, can u take a look at it ?

Comment: I feel like i'm missing just a few bits and pieces to the puzzle to finish this.. But I'm just not seeing it xD

Comment: @User987 Please check my updated answer. Make sure to return true (truthy value) or false (falsy value) from the jQuery validator based on whether the field value is valid or not respectively.

Comment: Hey, but the IsValid field returns a validation result, not a boolean type ?

Comment: @User987 `IsValid` is for the server side validation. To make it work on client side you need to write the jQuery unobtrusive validator which should return true or false based on whether the field value is valid or not on client side. You may choose to invoke your validation logic (not necessarily the `IsValid` method of your custom validator) on server from this client script. Whether the `IsValid` method of your custom validator returns success or faliure has nothing to do with client side validation.

Comment: aha so baically when I get the email value, I Invoke a method in my controller to check whether an email exists or not, and based on that I return either true or false ?

Comment: @User987 exactly. Invoking Web API instead of controller can also be an option, but that depends on you entirely.

Comment: So if i returned false , the validation shouldn't trigger at all right ?

Comment: Okay got it, gonna accept ur answer now, thansk ! :)

Comment: i have another issue now, I asked a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44998226/jquery-custom-unobstrusive-validator-not-working-properly