# jQuery custom unobstrusive validator not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, unobtrusive-validation

I have written a custom jQuery unobstrusive validation rule which looks like this:

```
<script>
    $.validator.addMethod("emailvalidate", function (value, element)
    {
        {
            var isSuccess;
            $.post("/Front/CheckEmail", { email: value }).done(function (data) {

                console.log("called");
                isSuccess = data === "true" ? true : false
            });
            console.log(isSuccess);
            return isSuccess;
        }});
    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("emailvalidate", function (options) {
        options.rules["emailvalidate"] = true;
        if (options.message) {
            options.messages["emailvalidate"] = options.message;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Please note the part with:

```
Console.log("called");
```

and this one:

```
console.log(isSuccess);
```

The way this gets written out in console is like following:

```
"undefined"
"called"
```

Which means the variable is returned before I can even make the call towards myserver, thus leaving the field always invalidated...

what am I doing wrong here guys?

Comment: An odd issue, how can return statement be called before the post itself ??

Comment: `$.post` is asynchronous, thus somehow you need to wait before returning the value. Best thing to do in my opinion is to make use of  [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) in such scenarios.

Comment: @SayanPal is this good enough:  jQuery.ajaxSetup({ async: false }); ?

Comment: Personally, I have not much used `async: false`, use it if it floats your boat :)