# Is custom server side validation in ASP.NET MVC automatically transferred to client side?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have to add validation to an ASP.NET MVC project, I'm doing some basic validation of a form for textboxes and radio buttons. Some textboxes are hidden unless specific radio button values are selected, in that case they shown up. All displayed textbox values are required.

If I create a custom server side validation for that part, should I add the same thing as a separate jQuery script or it should be working on client-side too?

```
    {
        [Required]
        [IsQuestionRequired]
        public List<Result> QuestionResults{ get; set; }
    }
public class Result
    {
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
        public int ResultID{ get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string ResultValue{ get; set; }
}
```

Inside the custom validation attribute IsQuestionRequired I would check if there is a result with specific ID (if there is resultID 10 in the list of results, than this field is required for resultID=16)

Comment: Short answer: it depends. Show the specific validation code you're talking about.

Comment: both of them,it's in the best if you consider all of the security issues from server and client sides

Comment: @Abofazl no, OP is asking whether MVC will automatically create some client side validation code based on what they wrote on the server. Which, in some cases, it will. Which is why we need to see the exact code to know whether that will happen. P.s. client side validation doesn't actually provide any security since it's trivial to bypass it. All it provides is better user experience. So it's incorrect to talk about client side security in the context of a web application

Comment: OK, I know that client side validation is fo UX purpose only, but I have to add it. For default data annotations it's set by default on UI, I will add code of the custom method so you can see

Comment: So the `[IsQuestionRequired]` is a custom data annotation, am I right? If so then yes you'll need to write your own JavaScript for that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44997162/custom-data-annotation-validation-attribute-with-client-side-validation talks about the ways to do it, and you can find other links online too. P.S. I don't think it makes much sense to put `[Required]` on a List...it would validate that the list exists, but not whether it contains any items, or whether those items are valid.

Comment: I didn't know if there's any sense to put this attribute on the list, but tested, and didn't help, so yes it's stupid :).